# Limits of multivariable functions : How to find sequences that disprove their existence.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I understand that to check whether a multivariable function $f$ has a limit or is continuous for some coordinates - let's call them $x$ - one must find that :

$$\forall(x_n)_n \vert \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}{x_n}=x : \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}{f(x_n)=f(x)}$$

However, I must say I do not understand the *process* of finding such $(x_n)_n$ when *disproving* the existence of such a limit ; and our teacher has made no attempt to explain.

When giving the solutions to such problems, he just pulls a solution out of his hat and explains why it works. Which in my opinion completely fails to address the actual problem, checking that a solution works is usually **trivial**. So how would you go about finding such a sequence ?

In essence what I'm asking is not "What is the solution to such a problem" but "What is the process by which a solution is produced". There is perhaps a funny parallel to $P$ vs $nP$ where solutions to $nP$ problems are easy to check but hard to find.

---

For those that would prefer a concrete example, here is one. Study the existence of the following limit :
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)\,,\,(x, y)\ne(0, 0)}\frac{x^2y}{x+y}$$
( *You should find that such a limit does not exist, however what I am interested in is *how* you will go about finding two sequences such that they converge to $(0,0)$ but make the function itself converge to two different values*)

Comment: Have you tried $\{y_n\}=-\{x_n\}$?